What differences are there between the two editions of "Voices from Chernobyl"?
The Wikipedia article for Voices from Chernobyl (published as Chernobyl Prayer in the United Kingdom) states that:

Chernobyl Prayer was first published in Russian in 1997; a revised, updated edition was released in 2013.

Are there are any significant differences between the original and the 2013 revised version?

My copy of the book is the 2016 Penguin Classic, translated by Anna Gunin and Arch Tait. The text copyright is given as "Svetlana Alexievich, 1997, 2013”, indicating it is based on the 2013 revision. I have not been able to source a copy of the 1997 text, but a sample of the 2006 translation by Keith Gessen is available on Amazon, which allows the first few pages to be browsed. So although  detailed textual comparison is not possible, we can at least compare the tables of contents to get an idea how much the basic structure of the book changed.
Both texts are divided into three main sections, together with a Prologue/Introduction and a final chapter entitled "In place of an epilogue". The titles of the main sections have some changes: the 2006 version is divided into:

Part one: The Land of the Dead, Part two: The Land of the Living and
Part three: Amazed by sadness

while the 2013 revision has:


Land of the Dead, 2. The Crown of Creation and 3. Admiring disaster


in particular the title of Part two was substantially altered, while Part three changed from "sadness" to "disaster".
Both versions have an introductory part composed of a historical note and a chapter entitled "A solitary human voice", but the later text has an additional chapter "The author interviews herself on missing history and why
Chernobyl  calls our view of the world into question".
Looking now at Part one, I give here the chapter headings of each, with similar/identical titles in bold text:



1997 version
2013 version





Monologue on why people remember


About what can be talked about with the living and the dead
Monologue on how we can talk with both the living and the dead


About a whole life written down on doors
Monologue on a whole life written on a door



Monologue on a village on how they call the souls from heaven to weep and eat with them



Monologue on how happy a chicken would be to find a worm. And what is bubbling in the pot is also not forever



Monologue on a song without words



Three monologues on ancient fear, and on why one man stayed silent while the women spoke



Monologue on how man is only crafty in evil, but simple and open in his words on love


Soldiers’ chorus
The Soldiers’ Choir


About what radiation looks like



About a song without words



About a homeland



About repentance



By those who returned




It is immediately clear that the two versions have a similar number of chapters, but some of the material must have been reordered and divided up differently. In particular, in the 2013 version each of the main sections ends with a "choir" - here in the first section with "The Soldier's Choir". That was not the case for the earlier text, which has five chapters between "The Soldiers' chorus" and the section's end.
Part two shows a similar behaviour:



1997 version
2013 version




About old prophecies
Monologue on the old prophecies


About a moonlit landscape
Monologue on a moonscape


About a man whose tooth was hurting when he saw Christ fall
Monologue of a witness who had toothache when he saw Christ fall and cry out


Three monologues on the “walking ashes” and the “talking dust”



About a single bullet



About how we can’t live without Chekhov and Tolstoy
Monologue on how we can’t live without Tolstoy and Chekhov


About war movies
Monologue on what St Francis preached to the birds


A scream
Monologue without a title: a scream



Monologue in two voices: male and female



Monologue on how some completely unknown thing can worm its way into you



Monologue on Cartesian philosophy and on eating a radioactive sandwich with someone so as not to be ashamed


About a new nation
Monologue on our having long ago come down from the trees but not yet having come up with a way of making them grow into wheels


About writing Chernobyl
Monologue by a capped well


About lies and truths
Monologue about longing for a role and a narrative


People’s chorus
The folk choir



Finally, here is the comparison for the third section:



1997 version
2013 version




About what we didn’t know: Death can be so beautiful
Monologue on something we did not know: death can look so pretty


About the shovel and the atom
Monologue on how easy it is to return to dust


About taking measurements
Monologue on the symbols and secrets of a great country


About how the frightening things in life happen quietly and normally
Monologue on the fact that terrible things in life happen unspectacularly and naturally


About answers
Monologue on the observation that a Russian always wants to believe in something


About memories
Monologue on how defenceless a small life is in times of greatness


About loving physics
Monologue on physics, with which we were all one in love


About expensive salami
Monologue on something more remote than Kolyma, Auschwitz and the Holocaust


About freedom and the dream of an ordinary death
Monologue on freedom and the wish to die an ordinary death


About the shadow of death



About a damaged child
Monologue on a freak who is going to be loved anyway



Monologue on the need to add something to everyday life in order to understand it



Monologue on a mute soldier


About political strategy
Monologue on the eternal accursed questions: “What is to be done?” and “Who is to blame?”


By a defender of the Soviet government
Monologue of a defender of Soviet power


About instructions
Monologue on how two angels took little Olenka


About the facts
Monologue on the unaccountable power of one person over another


About why we love Chernobyl
Monologue on sacrificial victims and priests


Children’s chorus
The Children’s Choir


A solitary human voice
A lone human voice



